# How to call built-in VS command?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

How do I call Visual Studio's "Build Solution" command from a custom button in an extension?
I don't expect code as an answer to this (but that would be cool), -a link to a resource that explains it would be helpful enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extensions model changes too fast to keep up, but this is how I used to execute a command in one:

```
DTE2 dte = (DTE2)GetService(typeof(DTE));
dte.ExecuteCommand("VS.CommandName", [parameters (if any)…]);
```